# Display multiple <td> vertically instead of decreasing <td> width

Tags: html, css

I have a regular HTML table displaying content from an API.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My page is responsive.

When screenwidth is decreased so content does not fit the width, is it possible, with css, to make `<td>` acting like `<tr>`? So with the code above i would like to display 6 vertically aligned `<td>`?

Comment: This may help https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Comment: Something similar to this : https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using `display:block` and `width:100%` od `<td>`

```css
table tr td {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td> 
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want it in 2 column:

```css
table tr {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  float: left;
}
table tr td {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td> 
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this could be the following :

On basic display

```
.fullTable{
 display:'block';
}
.singleLineTable{
 display:'none';
}
```

and with your media query on the other display :

```
.fullTable{
 display:'none';
}
.singleLineTable{
 display:'block';
}
```

Heres is your HTML but it might overload the DOM a bit:

```
<table style="width:100%" class='fullTable'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:100%" class='singleLineTable'>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

This way you will only show one of your two table based on you what your media query